# Any free pdf to xps converter or pdf batch printing program?

Tags: pdf, printing, batch, xps

Any free pdf to xps converter or pdf batch printing program?

I need to print a bunch of PDFs, but program I'm using, Sumatra PDF, while very fast has troubles printing and files themselves seem buggy. Often a 1 MiB pdf would be converted to a 1 GiB print job. My printer has 16 MiB of RAM, so you can imagine how well this turns out. On the other hand, Acrobat Reader has problems opening my PDF and is veeery slow and doesn't work with some files. I noticed that when I convert PDFs to XPS, I have no problems printing them.

Comment: Note that XPS is the spooling format on Windows as well. So if you get a print job of 1 GiB you'll also get an XPS file of 1 GiB size ...

Comment: Actually, I just printed to XPS a file which made a 1.1GiB print job. The XPS version is ~4MiB.

Comment: This sounds more like a corrupted printer driver. Tried updating it?

Comment: No new versions are available and support seems to be discontinued. The driver is pretty old though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found program which solved my need. I decided to use  Evince http://projects.gnome.org/evince/. It's fast enough for my needs (scrolling pages full of graphics as fast as my mouse can turn the wheel) and prints well.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Foxit PDF Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/reader4.php) to print PDF files and never had problems. Once I used Sumatra PDF and it was problematic. I didn't like it and immediately uninstalled it.

Comment: I'll try again with Foxit. My problem is that I have a lot of PDF which have lots of graphics in them. So far only Sumatra PDF worked fine and it remembers the last displayed page in a PDF. I did try Foxit some time ago, but it was too slow for me.